# Stopping a function from running

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 sequential divs to display on a page, the page loads showing div 1, by going onto the 2nd it starts a timer, when that timer runs out it goes back to the first div. Navigating through to the next div should start the timer again. The timer function works OK on the first page but on the second page when it is called it is already running from the previous div and therefore ticks the time down twice as fast, and on the last div 3 times.

How can I get it to stop the currently running function then restart it?

Thanks,

```
$scope.timeLeft = 0;

   var timeoutRunner = function (timerLength) {
     $scope.timeLeft = timerLength;

     var run = function () {

       if ($scope.timeLeft >= 1) {
         console.log($scope.timeLeft);
         $scope.timeLeft--
         $timeout(run, 1000);
       } else if ($scope.timeLeft == 0){
         $scope.endTransaction();
       }
     }
     run();
   }

timeoutRunner(5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time I called the function it created a new instance of it and I was unable to stop it on demand so I found a way to say which instance I want running:

```
$scope.timeLeft = 0;
   var instanceRunning = 0;

   var timeoutRunner = function (timerLength, instance) {
     $scope.timeLeft = timerLength;
     instanceRunning = instance;

     var run = function () {
       if (instanceRunning == instance){
         if ($scope.timeLeft < 7 && $scope.timeLeft > 0){
           $('#timer-container').show();
         } else {
           $('#timer-container').hide();
         }
         if ($scope.timeLeft >= 1) {
           console.log($scope.timeLeft);
           $scope.timeLeft--
           $timeout(run, 1000);
         } else if ($scope.timeLeft == 0){
           $scope.endTransaction();
         }
       }
     }
     run();
   }


timeoutRunner(20, 1);
timeoutRunner(20, 2);
timeoutRunner(20, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some logic that calls `$timeout.cancel(timeoutRunner);`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you want to cancel your timeout exactly (view change? when you end the transaction?) But here is how you would do it:

```
$scope.timeLeft = 0;

var timeoutPromise = false;

var timeoutRunner = function (timerLength) {
    $scope.timeLeft = timerLength;
    var run = function () {
        if ($scope.timeLeft >= 1) {
            console.log($scope.timeLeft);
            $scope.timeLeft--
            timeoutPromise = $timeout(run, 1000);
        } else if ($scope.timeLeft == 0){
            $scope.endTransaction();
            $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);
        }
    }
    run();
}

timeoutRunner(5);
```